# extractall() method not working on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a script able to open a tkinter window, select a directory. Select within this folder the several *.zip files and making them unzipped.

My code doesn't give me errors but doesn't unzipp the files neither. I'm working with the extractall() method with python2.7

```
import zipfile,os,tkFileDialog,Tkinter,glob

root = Tkinter.Tk()
directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/Users/me/zips",title='Please select a directory')
if len(directory) > 0 :
    print ("Dossier OK")


for ArchivesZip in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,'*.zip')):
    print ArchivesZip
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(ArchivesZip, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall()
    zip_ref.close()
```

Many thanks for your advices.

Comment: What makes you think `zipfile.ZipFile()` can accept a directory? What are you trying to achieve, to extract a zipfile *to* the selected directory?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to unzip a bunch of zipfiles in the same directory. I thought the method zipfile.ZipFile() would accept the list of files contained in the directory.

Comment: I tried this one also :`for ArchivesZip in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,'*.zip')):
    print ArchivesZip
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(ArchivesZip, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall()
    zip_ref.close()`

Comment: `zipfile.ZipFile()` takes a *zipfile* filename only. Your other attempt looks correct to me; update your question add that attempt and tell us why that didn't work for you.

Comment: I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working just fine, but you are extracting the files to the *current working directory*. What that directory is depends on how you started your program.

You most likely want to explicitly specify a directory to extract the zipfile to. The directory the user choose is a good point to start:

```
for ArchivesZip in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,'*.zip')):
    print ArchivesZip
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(ArchivesZip, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall(directory)
    zip_ref.close()
```

Comment: Oh! Stupid of me. I thought the extractall() method could implicitly unzipp in the same directory than the selected files... Now, it is working. Thank you:)